# pop from list using index list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list1 = [1,2,5,6,7,8,10,41,69,78,83,100,105,171]
index_list = [0,4,7,9,10]
```

how do I pop an item from list1 using indexes from index_list?

```
output_list = [2,5,6,8,10,69,100,105,17]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list.remove(item)

```
for n in reversed(index_list):
    list1.remove(list1[n])
```

or list.pop(index)

```
for n in reversed(index_list):
    list1.pop(n)
```

Both methods are described here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Use [reversed()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed) on your index_list (assuming that the indices are always ordered like in the case you have shown), so you remove items from the end of the list and it should work fine.

Comment: Sure.. revert the indexes!

Comment: Note: `list.remove` might fail in case of duplicate elements.

Comment: @tobias_k yes, you are right. pop() is the preferred method here

Answer (score 1):

How about the opposite: Retain those elements that are *not* in the list:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,5,6,7,8,10,41,69,78,83,100,105,171]
>>> index_list = [0,4,7,9,10]
>>> index_set = set(index_list) # optional but faster    
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(list1) if i not in index_set]
[2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 69, 100, 105, 171]
```

Note: This does not modify the existing list but creates a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1,2,5,6,7,8,10,41,69,78,83,100,105,171]
index_list = [0,4,7,9,10]


print([ t[1] for t in enumerate(list1) if t[0] not in index_list])
```

> RESULT
>
> [2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 69, 100, 105, 171]

enumerate will create a structure like below.

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2),(2, 5),(3, 6),(4, 7),(5, 8),...(13, 171)]

Where t = (0,1) (index,item)
t[0] = index
t[1] = item
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
for index in sorted(index_list, reverse=True):
    list1.pop(index)

print (list1)
```

`pop()` has an optional argument index. It will remove the element in index

Comment: Sorry about the `print` statement. was working on a 2.7 environment